# CSS: adding label above and below line

Tags: css

Is it possible to achieve the attached result using CSS?.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsuiZ.jpg

Currently I am able to draw the circle and add single line. How can I add the label below the line? How to add the label on the right side of the circle?

My HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="circle"></div>
    <div id="line"></div>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
#circle {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200;
    left: 400px;
}

#line {
    height: 45px;
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left: 450px;
}
```

Comment: Im afraid I've read it a few times but im still not totally clear on your desired output..

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/LT4jq/1/ ?

Comment: The requirement I need is shown in the image which I have attached to my question. Need to draw multiple lines around circle with label above and below each line.

Comment: You know...sometimes the best way to go...is with an image! Seems like a lot of markup for a diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### HTML

```
<div id="circle1" class="circle"></div>
<div id="line1" class="line vertical" data-left="a" data-right="b" ></div>
<div id="line2" class="line horizontal" data-top="a" data-bot="b" ></div>
```

### CSS

```
/*initialize your element position using id's*/

#circle1{
    top: 200;
    left: 400px;
}
 #line1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left: 450px;
}

#line2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 355px;
}

/* Classes */

.circle {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}

.line.vertical {
    height: 45px;
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
}

.line.vertical:before{
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    content:attr(data-left);
    top:50%;
    left:10px;
}

.line.vertical:after{
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    content:attr(data-right);
    top:50%;
    right:10px;
}

.line.horizontal {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
}

.line.horizontal:before{
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    content:attr(data-top);
    right:10px;
    top:-50%;
}

.line.horizontal:after{
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    content:attr(data-bot);
    top:10%;
    left:0px;
}
```

### USAGE

1. for initializing your element position use id's.
2. for styling lines or circle add `line` or `circle` class
3. for implementing a vertical line add `vertical` class
4. for implementing a vertical line add `horizontal` class

http://jsfiddle.net/Q2LET/

answer similar to @Kamlesh Kushwaha

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css pseduo elements` for this purpose. However, you have to adjust the position and content separately for them.

CSS:

```
#line:before{
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    content:'A';
    top:50%;
    left:10px;
}
#line:after{
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    content:'B';
    top:50%;
    right:10px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/135/

For dynamic label text, you can also use this approach:

HTML:

```
<div id="circle"></div>
<div id="line" data-left="ABC" data-right="DEF" ></div>
```

CSS:

```
#line:before{
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    content:attr(data-left);/*This will display the attribute values as content*/
    top:50%;
    left:10px;
}
#line:after{
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    content:attr(data-right);/*This will display the attribute values as content*/
    top:50%;
    right:10px;
}
```

Demo for dynamic content: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/136/

Answer (score 0):

Cause everything is `position:absolute` i added also a label with an absolute position.
You can creat at any place, just play a little with `top` and `left`

Hope this helps.

```
<div id="circle"></div>
<div id="line"></div>
<label id="leftlabel">test<label>

#circle
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200;
    left: 400px;
}

#line
{
    height: 45px;
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left: 450px;
}
#leftlabel
{
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    left: 350px;
}
```

whatch this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/sk8c3/

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/HvsVG/

```
 <body>
    <div id="circle"></div>
    <div id="line"></div>
    <div id="label1">Label456</div>
    <div id="label2">Label123</div>
 </body>


    #circle
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
}

#line
{
    height: 45px;
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left: 450px;
}
#label1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 425px;
}
#label2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 47px;
    left: 510px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/2KLx6/29/

css

```
    .wrapper {
        position:relative;
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
    }
    .circle
        {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            border-radius: 50px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 200;
            left: 200px;
        }
    .line-right {
            width: 45px;
            border-top: 1px solid blue;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            left: 301px;
        }
    .line-left {
            width: 45px;
            border-top: 1px solid blue;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            left: 155px;
        }
    .line-bottom
        {
            height: 45px;
            border-left: 1px solid blue;
            position: absolute;
            top: 101px;
            left: 250px;
        }
    .txt-top {
        position:absolute;
        margin:-30px 0 0 0 ;
    }
    .txt-bottom {
        position:absolute;
        margin:10px 0 0 0 ;
    }
    .txt-left {
        position:absolute;
        margin:0 0 0 -45px ;
    }
    .txt-right {
        position:absolute;
        margin:0 0 0 20px ;
    }
```

html

```
 <div class="wrapper"> 
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="line-bottom">
        <span class="txt-left">text</span>
        <span class="txt-right">text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="line-right">
        <span class="txt-top">text</span>
        <span class="txt-bottom">text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="line-left">
        <span class="txt-top">text</span>
        <span class="txt-bottom">text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you need to adjust margin, or set a fixed width for your span (and display:inline-block), so you can ceneter the text